# Getting unique, non-redundant combinations in Julia array?

Tags: julia, combinations, unique

I have two arrays of variables I am comparing,

```
arr1 = [1,2,3]
arr2 = [1,2,3]
```

I would like to get each unique, **non-redundant** combination of variables. The initial unique combinations are:

```
(1,1), (1,2), (1,3)
(2,1), (2,2), (2,3)
(3,1), (3,2), (3,3)
```

But this set is further reduced, since comparing variable `1` with itself (and `2` with itself, etc.) is meaningless. Removing these, the set reduces to:

```
(1,2), (1,3)
(2,1), (2,3)
(3,1), (3,2)
```

Furthermore, there are redundant pairs since comparing variable 1 to variable 2 is the same as comparing variable 2 to variable 1. So the end result I'm looking for would be:

```
(1,2), (1,3), (2,3)
```

I can reason through the first bit:

```
# Generate combination arrays
sets = []
sy = 3
for i in 1:size(ellipseX)[2]
    set1 = repeat([i],sy)
    set2 = range(1,sy)
    newsets = cat(set1,set2,dims=2)
    sets = cat(sets,newsets,dims=1)
end
# Remove rows with same column values
for N in 0:sy-1
    rownum = 1+sy*N
    sets = sets[setdiff(1:end, rownum), :]
end
```

but removing the redundant pairs is a bit more tricky. Is there a much easier way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like a job for [Combinatorics.jl](https://github.com/JuliaMath/Combinatorics.jl).

```
using Combinatorics

arr1 = [1,2,3]
arr2 = [1,2,3]

arr = unique([arr1; arr2])
combs = combinations(arr,2) |> collect
 [1, 2]
 [1, 3]
 [2, 3]
```

If, for some reason you can't install Combinatorics.jl, a comprehension will also work.

```
n = length(arr)
combs = [(arr[i],arr[j]) for i = 1:n-1 for j = i+1:n]
(1, 2)
(1, 3)
(2, 3)
```

**Update:** If the arrays might have different numbers, another in-place filtering operation is required to make sure the output tuples have one element taken from `arr1` and the other element taken from `arr2`.

```
filter!(t->any(t .∈ (arr1,)) && any(t .∈ (arr2,)), combs)
```

Example:

```
arr1 = [1,2,3,4]
arr2 = [1,2,5]

U = unique([arr1; arr2])

n = length(U)
combs = [(U[i],U[j]) for i=1:n-1 for j=i+1:n]
filter!(t->any(t .∈ (arr1,)) && any(t .∈ (arr2,)), combs)
9-element Vector{Tuple{Int64, Int64}}:
 (1, 2)
 (1, 3)
 (1, 4)
 (1, 5)
 (2, 3)
 (2, 4)
 (2, 5)
 (3, 5)
 (4, 5)
```

Comment: In this case, an inplace filtering operation is required to give the correct output. I updated my answer to take this into account. BTW, your code does not give the expected result.

Comment: true, I corrected my answer

Answer (score 0):

*I'm not sure the previous answer actually answers your question, here is my interpretation of your problem when `arr1` and `arr2` have different values (eg. in this example, should `(3,4)` be included?)*

[`Iterators.product`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/iterators/#Base.Iterators.product) returns an iterator with the first part of your problem

```
julia> a1 = [1,2,3,4]

julia> a2 = [1,2,5]

julia> Iterators.product(a1, a2) |> collect
4×3 Matrix{Tuple{Int64, Int64}}:
 (1, 1)  (1, 2)  (1, 5)
 (2, 1)  (2, 2)  (2, 5)
 (3, 1)  (3, 2)  (3, 5)
 (4, 1)  (4, 2)  (4, 5)
```

then, filtering out those with repeated numbers:

```
julia> Iterators.filter(allunique, Iterators.product(a1, a2)) |> collect
10-element Vector{Tuple{Int64, Int64}}:
 (2, 1)
 (3, 1)
 (4, 1)
 (1, 2)
 (3, 2)
 (4, 2)
 (1, 5)
 (2, 5)
 (3, 5)
 (4, 5)
```

finally, you can use [`unique(f, itr)`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.unique) with `Set` to get the required result

```
julia> unique(Set, Iterators.filter(allunique, Iterators.product(a1, a2)))
9-element Vector{Tuple{Int64, Int64}}:
 (2, 1)
 (3, 1)
 (4, 1)
 (3, 2)
 (4, 2)
 (1, 5)
 (2, 5)
 (3, 5)
 (4, 5)
```

This solution can accept more than 2 input vectors